# Creating a tf.sequence_mask based on input values

Tags: python, tensorflow

The example given by the tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) shows that the mask can be created:

```
tf.sequence_mask([1, 3, 2], 5)  # [[True, False, False, False, False],
                                #  [True, True, True, False, False],
                                #  [True, True, False, False, False]]
```

What if I would like to create a dynamic mask based on the values of my batches? Say if my input is [[1, 0, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]], and I would like to mask everything up to the first 4 to be True and everything after the first 4 to be false, and the resulting mask should be:

```
[[True, True, True, True, True],
[True, True, True, False, False],
[True, True, True, False, False]]
```

I am trying to use this as weight to apply to my sequence_loss tensor

Comment: So ur one batch shape is [BATCH_SIZE , 3, 5] always? and what u mean by first 4 to be True? I dont see that in your resulting graph?

Comment: the batch size is fixed like the example I gave. Everything before the first 4 (including the first 4) that is seen should be masked as True. 4 is the element value in the batch as my batch contains numbers

Answer (score 3):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1, 0, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]])
​
cond = tf.cast(tf.equal(x, 4), tf.int8)
idx4_ = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(cond, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), (-1,1))
​
```

Optional if all rows have at least one value equal to 4:

```py
idx4 = tf.where(
    tf.equal(tf.reduce_max(cond, axis=1, keep_dims=True), 1), 
    idx4_, 
    tf.constant(-1, shape=idx4_.shape)
)
```

Create the mask by comparing the index of first 4 with a 1d range index:

```
mask = idx4 >= tf.range(x.shape[1])
​
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(mask))
#[[ True  True  True  True  True]
# [ True  True  True False False]
# [ True  True  True False False]]
```

---

Or use `sequence_mask`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1, 0, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]])
​
cond = tf.cast(tf.equal(x, 4), tf.int8)
idx4_ = tf.argmax(cond, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)

idx4 = tf.where(
    tf.equal(tf.reduce_max(cond, axis=1), 1), 
    idx4_, 
    tf.constant(-1, shape=idx4_.shape)
)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.sequence_mask(idx4+1, x.shape[1])))

#[[ True  True  True  True  True]
# [ True  True  True False False]
# [ True  True  True False False]]
```

---

If x is a placeholder with unknown shape before hand:

```
import tensorflow as tf
​
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None,None])
cond = tf.cast(tf.equal(x, 4), tf.int8)
idx4_ = tf.argmax(cond, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)

idx4 = tf.where(
    tf.equal(tf.reduce_max(cond, axis=1), 1), 
    idx4_, 
    tf.fill(tf.shape(idx4_), -1)
)

mask = tf.sequence_mask(idx4+1, tf.shape(x)[-1])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(mask, {x: [[1, 0, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]]}))

#[[ True  True  True  True  True]
# [ True  True  True False False]
# [ True  True  True False False]]
```

Comment: what if x is not constant? I am running batches and I would like to change my mask based on the value of the batches. Also, could I achieve it using sequence_mask?

Comment: It should still work if `x` is a variable, updated a solution when `x` is a placeholder with the `sequence_mask` method.